# Find object in json array Using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, lodash

I am trying to find the index of an object containing (`From:`) inside a JSON array
so I did a recursive function to find the `From:` text and i used `Lodash` and `FindIndex` function but it is not working as expected and it is always returning `-1`

My code:

```
    // item is the actual object in the json array
   // arr is the parent holding item 
  // mdfdoc is the whole json array
 static handleText(item, mdfdoc, arr) {
    try {
        let theText = item.type === "text" ? item.text : item.content.text
        if (theText && theText.replace(/\s/g, '') != "") {
                if (theText === "From:") {
                    const index = _.findIndex(mdfdoc, arr);
                    console.log(index);
                }
        }
    }
    catch(ex){console.log(ex)}
}
```

object:

```
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "From:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Bassem Alameddine <bassem.alameddine@test.com> "
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Sent:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Tuesday, August 2, 2022 12:28 PM"
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "To:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Bassem Alameddine <bassem.alameddine@test.com>"
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Subject:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
```

Full Array:

```
{
  "type": "doc",
  "version": 1,
  "content": [
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Testing",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "em"
        },
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "dadas",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "em"
        },
        {
          "type": "strong"
        },
        {
          "type": "textColor",
          "attrs": {
            "color": "#ff0000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " "
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "From:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Bassem Alameddine <bassem.alameddine@test.com> "
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Sent:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Tuesday, August 2, 2022 12:28 PM"
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "To:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " Bassem Alameddine <bassem.alameddine@test.com>"
    },
    {
      "type": "hardBreak"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": "Subject:",
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "strong"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " "
    }
  ]
}
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " "
    }
  ]
},
{
  "type": "paragraph",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "text": " "
    }
  ]
}
 ]
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't look very recursive to me.

Comment: Yes because i didn't post the whole logic it is too big to post it

Comment: Then it's hard to say what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

use this function it will search you the key if it is in object

```
function searchIndexByKey(arr, key){
 var re = -1;
    for(var p=0;p<arr.length;p++){
    var obj = arr[p];
    var res= searchObjectByKey(obj, key, p);
    if(res>=0){
      re = res;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(re>=0){
    return re;
  }else{
   return -1;
  }
}

function searchObjectByKey(obj, k, index) {
  
for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];

    if (k == key) {
      return index;
      break;
    }

    if (typeof(value) === "object" && !Array.isArray(value)) {
      var y = searchObjectByKey(value, k, index);
      if (y && y[0] == k) return y;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; ++i) {
        var x = searchObjectByKey(value[i], k, index);
        if (x && x[0] == k) return x;
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

var arr = [
{
  "type": "doc",
  "version": 1,
},
{
  "type1": "doc",
  "version1": 1,
}];
  
console.log(searchIndexByKey(arr,'type'));
```

Comment: and how will this function help me in finding the index?

Comment: what index? its object not an array , provide me array so i can modified this function @Sora

Comment: I already have the object need to find the index of this object inside my array
I guess you understand my question wrong!!

Comment: hey @Sora, i have updated answer please check

Answer (score 0):

```
// if more than one index occurs it will return an array of indexes
const isTextHasFrom = (text) => text === "From:";
const getArrayOfIndex = (acc, item, index) => {
  const getText = item.type === "text" ? item.text : item?.content;
  if (typeof getText === "string") {
    if (isTextHasFrom(getText)) {
      acc.push(index);
    }
  } else {
    if (item.content.some(({ text }) => isTextHasFrom(text))) {
      acc.push(index);
    }
  }
  return acc;
};

const indexes = data.reduce(getArrayOfIndex, []);
console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: This will not work for me as your code will return the index of `item` inside `arr` and not inside `mdfdoc`, i need to find the index of `arr` inside `mdfdoc`

Comment: @Sora I didn't get your question. Whats the difference between mdfdoc and parent Array ain't they same ?

Comment: No
mfdoc is the whole Json 
parent array is the one containing the `text:"From:"` which is the `Object` in my question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote simple recurssive function that return firstIndex that has From:

```
const findFromArr = (obj, index = 0) => {
    if (obj.type === "text") {
        return obj.text.includes("From:") ? index : false
    } else {
        const index = obj.content.findIndex((obj, index) => {
            const result = findFromArr(obj, index)
            return result
        })
        return index;
    }

}
```

you can simply your whole json to this function.

Comment: can you provide an example of how to use the function please

Comment: const indexOfElement =  findFromArr(obj);

Comment: but incase the we have multiple `obj` with `From:` it will always return the first one

Comment: Actually, I thought you only needed to have the first index retrieved.

Comment: no i need to find the index every time my function detect a `text="From:"`